# MongoDB randomly fail to drop sharded database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, database

I have few integration tests that use real [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) database version 3.2. Tests are run with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and I'm dropping the test db after each test with following code. It uses [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) version 4.4.12 and native MongoDB Node.js driver.

```
afterEach((done) => {
    const connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.db.host);
    connection.once("open", () => {
    connection.db.command({ dropDatabase: 1 })
        .then((res) => done(null, res))
        .catch(done);
    });
})
```

It worked nicely until I enabled sharding in my local environment to cover that with tests as well. Dropping database started to fail randomly. Above code fails to drop my test db about on every third test run. My sharding setup is minimal and have one config server, one mongos and two mongo shards.

After I added some logging I noticed that `connection.db.command({ dropDatabase: 1 })` returns `{ info: 'database does not exist', ok: 1 }` on those failed runs. Database is not dropped because MongoDB thinks it is already dropped even it is not the case.

Am I doing it completely wrong? Is there some Mongoose / MondoDB Node.js native driver configuration or such that I'm missing here? Or is this some known problem? Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Same thing happens if I use [MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Db.html#command) directly, so Mongoose is not causing this.

Comment: There is a known issue in dropping a database or a collection in a sharded cluster. Please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17397 for more details and workaround. You can also upvote and watch the issue for any updates.